# Previous Calendar date not coming as expected, need a workaround

Tags: java, date, calendar

> The following code gives incorrect output - 29/01/2015, should give 29/12/2015.
>   Please provide a work around to get the correct value.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
public class CheckTime{

public static void main(String... x) throws Exception{

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
    Date date = formatter.parse("31/12/2015");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    System.out.println(day+"/"+month+1+"/"+year);
}
}
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Don't think the duplicate marked question has any relation to this question. Here the problem is with wrong date format (along with couple of other mistakes).

Comment: @MrinalK.Samanta: Thanks, now I must test. I'm also concerned that he's not doing `"+ (month + 1) + "` Ah yes, he's using `mm` and not `MM`. my bad. I'll re-open.

Comment: yes, that is one of the mistakes I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: I understand that months start with 0, but what is the solution to this?

Comment: @Akshit Change your date format to "dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: Oh.. my bad, it was a silly mistake! Working fine after change to "dd/MM/yyy". Thanks @MrinalK.Samanta

Comment: @Akshit Please search StackOverflow before posting. You would have found hundreds of examples of working code you could have compared to your own code to find the fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Wrong Format Pattern

As the comments discuss, the format pattern used lowercase `mm` (minute-in-hour) where it should have used uppercase `MM` (month-in-year).

## java.time

Java 8 and later comes with the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework that supplants the old date-time classes used in the Question. These new classes are a *vast* improvement. Avoid the old.

Among the new classes is one to track a date-only value without time-of-day or time zone: [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

Standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats are used by default in parsing and generating String representations of date-time values. As your string inputs are in a different format, we must specify a coded pattern.

```
String input = "31/12/2015";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "dd/MM/yyyy" );
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse ( input, formatter );
```

We can easily find the previous and next days. Note the use of [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) pattern. Rather than alter member fields of an object, we create a new object based on the old object’s values. Much safer for [value objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) such as date-time.

```
LocalDate previousDay = localDate.minusDays ( 1 );
LocalDate nextDay = localDate.plusDays ( 1 );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "localDate: " + localDate + "  previousDay: " + previousDay + "  nextDay: " + nextDay  );
```

> localDate: 2015-12-31  previousDay: 2015-12-30  nextDay: 2016-01-01